# How to prove that the intersection of 3 planes is a line?

Tags: analytic-geometry

Consider the planes:
$$P1:x - y = 0$$
$$P2:y-z = 0$$
$$P3:-x+z = 0$$
Prove that the intersection of the planes is a line.

`My solution:`
Solving the system I've obtained that $x=y=z$ and I made the notation $x=t$. From here we get the parametric equations of a line $d$ and we can write the canonical form:
$$ d : {{x}\over1} = {{y}\over 1} = {{z}\over1} $$
Thus proving that the intersection of the 3 planes is a line. Is this correct? If so, are there any other ways to prove this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Obviously $(0,0,0)$ and $(1,1,1)$ are solutions, hence the line determined by these points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is correct and it is the simplest way to prove what you want.